# Does the following condition characterise convexity of a set?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-analysis

Conjecture: A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if and only if the following holds.

For any $x \in X$ and any vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x+v \notin X$, it holds that for any scalar $a$ with $1 \leq a$ we have that $x+av \notin X$.

Comment: Try to restate your condition in contrapositive way, and see what it says.

Comment: Well the contrapositive basically says $\forall x,v,a (x \in X, v \in R^n, 1 \leq a, x+av \in X \rightarrow x+v \in X)$. I don't know how to manipulate it any further....

Comment: Introduce a letter $y=x+av$ and write the vector $x+v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: @copper.hat: can I borrow your $n$-dimensional graph paper?

Comment: @robjohn: You can of course, as long as its $n=2$... (Albeit, for this problem, one dimensional graph paper is sufficient :-).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose X convex. Then if $x\in X$ and $x+v\notin X$, then $x+av\notin X$ for $a\geq1$ because X is convex and the contrary will imply that $x+v\in X$. On the other hand, suppose your condition. Take two points $x$ and $y$ in X. Then if $y+t(x-y)\notin X$ for some $t_{0}$ between $(0,1)$, we have $y+t(x-y)\notin X$ for all $t\geq t_{0}$. Then, we will must have $x\notin X$. Contradiction!